# GNOME 3 Theme fallback

Tags: 11.10, gnome, themes

Recently I noticed this issue about GNOME 3 themes (see attached screenshot). Edit: GNOME shows some default Gtk theme, instead of the configured one like Ambiance.

This happened after gnome-accessibility-themes has been updated.

How to solve this?

[image: GNOME 3 Theming Issue]

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/879793

Answer (score 1):

This seens to be [Bug #879793](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/879793). At the time it is discussed in Launchpad. The developer tries to reproduce it and find a solution. It might be good idea to check the report for news and additional information.